# What is the refresh rate of the command prompt window?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I am recording my command prompt window. I want to record it at 60 fps, but if the command prompt window's refresh rate is capped at 30 fps, then I'll record it at 30 fps.

I have this question is because my video editor's auto fps selector selects 30fps even when I record at 60.

My monitor and display settings is 60 hz.

Comment: Windows don't have a refresh rate. They update when the program or Windows tells them too - ie when something happens. EG user presses key, program prints to window.

Comment: @user1292580 But if I write a script print 1 line every 1 ms, the window will not update 1000 times a second obviously. Is it just because my monitor can't show 1000 hz, or windows itself has some frame rate cap?

Comment: Windows itself has no frame rate cap. The monitor refresh rate is typically the limit, which is information that your video card automatically retrieves. Command prompt outputs are all "blocking" outputs, meaning if you tell it to sequentially output 1, 2, 3, 4, it has to output them all and not arbitrarily drop them due to display output speed. You'll have to do some testing on whether the monitor rate is your limit or whether there's another limit.

Comment: You'll have to setup a way to display a bunch of output, record at the FPS, and see if each line is captured per frame. Of course, the moment there is a split second delay in your output, it'll throw everything off. I'm not sure why you need your FPS to match it either.

Comment: The window will try to update every 1ms. As a program only gets 20ms of time to execute code before the processor switches to another thread (and there is lots of threads but only threads that can execute code are switched too - most threads are waiting for something) so only 20 updates are made **to memory** per whatever. The display driver goes through display memory and builds something for the monitor on it's frame rate.

Comment: I'm working with python. I can write an infinite loop to print something, command prompt will continuously print it, not dump at once, maybe different language have different behavior.

Comment: @JeffreyChen Not different languages, as Windows only works one way, but different techniques.